# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' using CSV file

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I have this python code trying use  langchain library in Python but I have an issue apparently about the CSV file I already checked the file and I didn't see any issue.

[Code in python part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh9I0.png)

[Code in python part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWKwI.png)

[This is the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrRlj.png)

I appreciate if somebody can help!

Comment: I suggest you paste your code, not images so we can copy & paste